# Java SpringMVC where to place the RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration (@Configuration) file

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have come across so many tutorials about configuration files for java SpringMVC projects  and usually have the @Configuration at their class name but they never mention where exactly to place these files.

For example I have learnt that I might be able to change Spring Data Rest rest api by extending the RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.

1) I want to be able to be able to have longer urls for the repositories so instead of having api/amazonproducts I could have api/amazon/products. Apparently this is impossible. I end up having;

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "amazonproducts", path = "amazonproducts")
@CrossOrigin
public interface AmazonProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<AmazonProduct, Long> {
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.html

All I have to do is for example create class like;

```
class CustomRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

  @Override
  @Bean
  public HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver() {

    HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = super.pageableResolver();
    resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
    return resolver;
  }
}
```

I don't know in which file/folder to place this code. I am using Eclipse Java EE Oxygen. I have created a maven project and I am currently testing it on spring-boot

Comment: Provide reasons for the vote down please. It is a simple question of where and how. A link to a tutorial perhaps.

Comment: You can place them wherever you want actually (talking about 100% java config)! Spring will find them. I would start with a minimal working example and slowly work your way to what you want to achieve. Plenty of examples on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place `@Configuration` annotated classes in any package you want, as long as the package is included in the component scanning.

In Spring Boot, that by default means in the same package as the class with [`@SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html), or **any subpackage** thereof, same as for all other classes managed by Spring.

Other than that, Spring doesn't care about package names.